# Numpy combining 2 arrays

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have 2 arrays I'd like to **combine**:

```
x1 = np.zeros((10,37632))
x2 = np.zeros((10,4))
```

... into x3.shape = (**10**, 37632, 4)

**Want:** 
Given x1 and x2, make x3 ... The shape of x3 should be (10, 37632, 4).  The original data in x1 and x2 should be intact.

**Tried:** 
I've tried reshape, append, expand_dims,block,hstack, etc. but I'm new to numpy and python.  For instance,

> x3=np.append(x1,x2, axis=1)

... gives me a shape of (10, 3763**6**).  This is not what I need.

Btw - I used "np.zeros" above, but in my app, I have 10 images (37632 = 112 x 112 x 3) and 4 model scores for each image.  That's "x1" and "x2". I need to keep the data intact.  "x3" will be passed into Keras.

Thanks for your help or pointers!

Comment: You can't combine the arrays into that shape. The number of elements in x1 and x2 do not sum up to the number of elements in a shape (10, 37632, 4) array

Answer (score 0):

I think you mis-understand what a 3-d array means!

examples - 
when we say a shape of `(2,2)`, we mean {putting random numbers.}

```
[1,2
 3,4]
```

when we say a shape of `(2,2,2)`, we mean {putting random numbers.}

```
[[1,2],[3,4]
 [5,6],[7,8]]
```

That is that there's literally another dimension to the input! 
Think of a `(2,2)` shape as a normal 2-d matrix in a paper. adding a third dimension, think of the numbers in each cell coming out of the paper!

So to go from `(10,37632)` to `(10,37632,4)` , each of the cell in your `(10,37632)` matrix which currently has only a single number, has to be a list of 4 numbers!

Hope it helps!

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'm trying to do.   Just don't know how.   I'm sure I don't understand 3-d ... and so many other things.
<br><br>
I may have to reframe my thinking.   What I have is 10 images each with 112 x 112 pixels and 1 channel of RBG (so, 3 values).   This essentially a (10,112,112,3).   I'm trying to attach the 4 model scores for each image.  That's a (10, 4).
<br><br>
I may end up using append to end up with an array (10,112,112,7) ...